# how can I call partial view from button click event

Tags: asp.net-core, partial-views

I have a partail view _delete.cshtml  in view\shared folder. I want to call the partial view from the button click event of index.cshtml

```html
@model DeleteViewModel
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">@Model.ConfirmationTitle</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @Model.ConfirmationMesssge
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to call the _delete view from Index html . How can I call _delete partial view from here

```html
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger m-1" data-toggle="modal">
                                Delete
                            </button>
```

When I click the Delete button of partial view I want to call the action method Delete() from the HomeController.

```
public IActionResult Delete(Product product )
 {

   return View()        

}
    public IActionResult Delete(Product product )
 {
   return View()        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo like below:

Model:

```
public class DeleteViewModel
{
    public string ConfirmationTitle { get; set; } = "Delete confirmation";
    public string ConfirmationMesssge { get; set; } = "Are you sure you want to Delete ?";
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    public string productName { get; set; }
    public int productPrice { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}
```

View(Index.cshtml):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger m-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Delete
</button>
@await Html.PartialAsync("_Delete")
```

Partial View:

```
@model DeleteViewModel
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">@Model.ConfirmationTitle</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @Model.ConfirmationMesssge
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <form asp-action="Delete">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Product.productName" />
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Product.productPrice" />
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Product.quantity" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var model = new DeleteViewModel() { 
        Product= new Product()
        {
            productName="aa",
            productPrice=34,
            quantity=2
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Delete(Product product)
{
    //do your stuff..
    return Json("OK");
}
```

Result:
[image]